# How do I send a message without using the deprecated way "sendMessage" in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

How do I send a message to a channel in discord.js? I know how but `msg.channel.sendMessage` is becoming deprecated. How can I send a message without it being deprecated, and not using `msg.reply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
message.channel.send("Message Content");
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=send

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do `message.channel.send(“text to send”)`
If you want to do a specific channel you can do the following

```
 Let messageChannel = message.guild.channels.find(“name”, “general”)
 messageChannel.send(“your message”)
```